# install compass with ansible

Tags: rubygems, ansible, compass

I'm trying to use Ansible to install compass, which is needed for one of our services, on an EC2 server.
Usually we install it manually using the following commands -

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.2
rvm use 2.1.2 --default
gem install compass
```

And then run compass compile successfully.
Now when I try to run these commands with an Ansible playbook (using the shell module) the compass command is not found by the system.

I have tried using RVM official Ansible role (https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-ansible), and all I got is more errors.

I've tried installing rubydev and rubygems-integration using apt and then installing the gem using the gem module. This does recognise the compass command but when I try to compile or even show the compass version it returns errors. Here is the error for running compass -v, for example:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["25"] of /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/compass/version.rb: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/compass/../../VERSION.yml
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

This is the playbook that managed to install compass, but left me with the errors I've mentioned:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  become: yes
  become_method : sudo
  tasks:
    - name: install ruby-dev
      apt: 
        name: ruby-dev
    - name: install rubygems
      apt: 
        name: rubygems-integration
    - name: install ruby compass
      apt: 
        name: ruby-compass
  ...
```

Would love some help.

Comment: Can you post your playbook?

Comment: What task is it failing on?

Comment: Like I wrote above - the current playbook runs successfully, but when I try to run compass compile or even compass -v it fails (while installing it manually works fine)

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the `source` step of the compile command. Ansible opens a new shell for every task so you would need to do something like this in a task: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc && rvm install 2.1.2 && rvm use 2.1.2 --default && gem install compass`. How do you try to use the compass compile command with Ansible?

Comment: The error I'm getting is too long but the gist of it is - 
You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.
The error should be fixed by rvm use 2.1.2 --default so I've tried running rvm use 2.1.2 --default && /usr/bin/gem install compass and it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the playbook that eventually worked for me for installing compass -

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  become: yes
  become_user : deploy3
  tasks:
    #- name: get gpg
    #  shell: "gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3"
    - name: install rvm
      shell: "curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable"
    - name: install rvm 2.1.2
      shell: "/home/deploy2/.rvm/bin/rvm install 2.1.2"
    - name: use rvm 2.1.2 by default and install compass
      shell: "bash -lc \"/home/deploy2/.rvm/bin/rvm use 2.1.2 --default && /home/deploy3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem install compass\""
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use gem module it's better than shell script because it doesn't depend on Linux distributions you use, example:

One playbook example

```
- name: Installing ruby
  apt:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - ruby2.0
    - ruby2.0-dev

- name: Symlink exists for Ruby 2.0
  file: src=/usr/bin/ruby2.0 dest=/usr/local/bin/ruby state=link

- name: Symlink exists for Ruby Gems 2.0
  file: src=/usr/bin/gem2.0 dest=/usr/local/bin/gem state=link

- name: install compass
  gem:
    name: compass
    state: latest
```

By the way, you can see more about gem module here into ansible documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/gem_module.html